# What's the difference between invocation_id and build_id in Bazel?

Tags: bazel

Looking at the outputs from Bazel's [build event protocol](https://bazel.build/remote/bep), I can see that the BEP output only has one unique `invocation_id` (which makes sense) and also only one unique `build_id` (even when building multiple targets at once).

In that case, what's the point of `build_id`?

Answer (score 1):

A higher-level system that uses Bazel (e.g., a CI system) may have a concept of a build that is broader than one Bazel invocation. For instance, the higher-level system may retry entire Bazel invocations under certain circumstances or allow a "build" to contain multiple Bazel build or test steps. The build id allows multiple Bazel invocations composing a high-level build to be correlated in Bazel's metadata emissions (most notably, the Build Event Protocol).